# How to navigate through rows of a datagrid via buttons in compact framework?

Tags: c#, datagrid, row

I have a data grid and buttons beside it with which i want to navigate through the data grid : Next Row, First Row, Last Row, Previous Row.

When i hit for example "Previous row", I want the previous row to be selected obviously :D.

```
dataGrid.CurrentRowIndex = dataGrid.CurrentRowIndex-1;
```

moves only the index of the cell but not the selection.

I could do this

```
DataGrdid.Select(thedesiredrow)
```

but this doesn't deselect the previously selected rows.
Is there a method to deselect every previously selected (multiple) row  in compact framework or is there an more elegant way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
MyDataGrid.SelectedIndex = "Here put number for the new selected item";
```

Comment: Maybe i am wrong but this seems not to be valid for the .Net "Compact framework".

    SelectedIndex
may be for listBox ?